# Recursive implementation of strcat function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion

I was going through the [implementation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-one-line-functions-for-strcat-and-strcmp/)! of **strcat** function in C.
I am unable to understand how they have used the **recursion** along with **pointers**.

*Below is the code Snippet from that source.*

```
char dest[100] = "I love";
char *src = "food";`

/* my_strcat(dest, src) copies data of src to dest. */
void my_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
  (*dest)? my_strcat(++dest, src): (*dest++ = *src++)? my_strcat(dest, src): 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What bit didn't you understand

Comment: consider posting to [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) which deals with curiosities rather than practicalities

Comment: @M.M according to the code till the dest pointer not reaches Null it keeps on calling  my_strcat(++dest,src)  and when dest encounters NULL we go for *dest++ == *src++ now this will return the value *src which will be taken as true now why they again calling my_strcat(dest,src) for true condition instead of just copying all the elements of src to dest.

Comment: because they wanted to do it that way for fun

Comment: @M.M why they want to have fun making things complex?

Comment: see the title of the page you linked, "Write one line functions for strcat()"  . the point of this page is to do things in an unusual way for fun

Comment: It's called Obfuscated C (or whatever language).  That is, doing something in an unusual way *in order to make it hard to understand*.  Unfortunately, this version has a bug, see my answer.

Comment: @MAP Although the function itself may not be perfect, the snippet as a whole is correct. Which is to say that `dest[100]` *will* be filled with all NULs after the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking it into pieces:

```
(*dest) /* Is *dest different than '\0' ? */
   ? my_strcat(++dest, src) /* *dest is different than '\0', so increment dest pointer so it'll point to the next character and call my_strcat() again. Here we're searching for the end of the string dest. */

   : (*dest++ = *src++) /* *dest is equal to '\0', so we're at the end of *dest... We start to assign *src to *dest and increment both pointers to point to the next character. The lvalue of this assignment is also a comparison (is it different than '\0' ?). */

     ? my_strcat(dest, src) /* The previous comparison is different than '\0', so we'll call my_strcat() again (pointers have already been incremented and they now point to the next character) */

     : 0; /* The previous comparison is '\0', so we've reached the end of the src, so we're done. */
```

Replacing ternary operators with if/else:

```
/* Is *dest different than '\0' ? */
if (*dest != '\0') {
  /* *dest is different than '\0', so increment dest pointer so it'll point to the next character and call my_strcat() again. Here we're searching for the end of the string dest. */
  my_strcat(++dest, src);
} else {
  /* *dest is equal to '\0', so we're at the end of *dest... We start to assign *src to *dest and increment both pointers to point to the next character. The lvalue of this assignment is also a comparison (is it different than '\0' ?). */
  if ((*dest = *src) != '\0') {
    /* The previous comparison is different than '\0', so we'll call my_strcat() again (pointers have already been incremented and they now point to the next character) */
    my_strcat(++ dest, ++ src); /* Moved increments down for readability */
  } else {
     /* The previous comparison is '\0', so we've reached the end of the src, so we're done. */
    return; 
  }
}
```

If/else without comments (maybe it's more readable):

```
if (*dest != '\0') {
  my_strcat(++dest, src);
} else {
  if ((*dest = *src) != '\0') {
    my_strcat(++ dest, ++ src);
  } else {
    return; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty poor implementation, but I guess it *does* work.  The first `?:` tests if the destination string is at end.  If not it bumps the destination pointer and then calls itself recursively.  If the destination is already at the end, it then copies one character, bumping both pointers and tests for zero.  If that wasn't the trailing `NUL` from src, it then calls itself recursively with the updated pointers.

Oh, wait, there's a bug (or maybe a "feature").  It assumes that all of the characters after the end of dest are initially filled with `NUL`s.  I guess you could actually leverage that, if you can rely on the implemention continuing to have this property and have a dest string with text interspersed with `NUL` characters and it would fill in those `NUL`s out of `src`, one character at a time.

And that's not to mention the excessive use of recursion which means that you will have as many call frames on the stack as there are characters in the resulting string.  Where did you get this silly `strcat` implementation from?  Certainly no real library would use this implementation, the iterative variant is both easier to understand and much faster.

Comment: I have mentioned the link of source.

Comment: Yes, it was a rhetorical question.

Comment: I think you are right there is a bug because all characters can't be NULL they would be zero. but if they are zero then also it's ok isn't it?

Comment: Characters can't be `NULL`, only pointers can.  Characters are `NUL` and you're only guaranteed one at the end, the rest of the array could be filled with anything.  And, BTW in almost all implementations, both `NULL` and `NUL` are actually zero.

Comment: @MAP `NUL` is defined as `0` by the ASCII specification.  The C specification only talks about characters with value zero, not NUL.

Comment: Maybe a bug  in general use.  But not as posted.  `char dest[100] = "I love";` does fill all 100  locations of `dest[]` mostly with null characters.  So `my_strcat()` works.